# what is the condition for the laurent series coefficient become zero?

Tags: laurent-series

the original text is from brown's textbook *complex variables and applications*, which said

> we want to find out the series of "$ e^{1/z}$",and
> since we have already known the maclaurin series expansion
> $$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
> we replace $z$ by $1/z$ to get
> $$e^{1/z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!z^n}$$
> note that no positive powers of z appear hear, **since the coefficient of the positive powers are zero**.

why is that?
And there is another text said that

> observe that the integrand in expression (3) can be written $f(z)(z-z_0)^{n-1}$.Thus it is clear that when $f$ is actually analytic throughout the disk$|z-z_0|<R_2$, this integrand is too. **Hence all of the coefficients $b_n$ are zero**

and why is that?
the $b_n$ coefficients of Laurent series are
$$b_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{-n+1}}dz$$
Thank you very much if anyone could give my any suggestions.

Comment: This seems like two different questions.  It might make sense to ask them separately.  Also, what is (3) in the second quoted text?

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's just the expression of $b_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have figured it out both problem: Both are  because $b_n$ is analytic throughout the entire region of $R_0$, so that its closed path integral is actually equal to zero. and for $a_n$, it has a singularity point at $z=0$, thus its integral is not $0$.